# How to insert in 'actionsheet ..Facebook and Twitter function in app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, uibutton, uiactionsheet

How can I insert in actionsheet two buttons with two functions facebook and Twitter (social.framework)?

Answer (score 0):

Christian,  See my other answer for your other question.  Ray Wenderlich's site has a great tutorial on this.  They also have a great book iOS 6 by tutorials that shows you how to do all this.  It really lets you understand the basics of the new social.framework.  They teach you how to get Facebook and Twitter in an action sheet and how to make your own action to put on the sheet.  Even if you just follow the online tut, you will gain a lot of information.  Try it out!

http://www.raywenderlich.com

Go to the tutorial tabs and scroll around to see a ton of useful info.  Hope this helps.